# Intellij restart

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, restart, spring-boot-devtools

I'm having trouble restarting my project when I run it even with springboot dev-tools and IDE configured to do so.
[GitHub's link](https://github.com/Dhionata/credit-application-system) from the project.
Attached are prints of my IDE settings.

- [Build project automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfyWx.png)
- [Allow auto-make to start even if developed application is currently running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5toci.png)
- [Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWuhA.png)
- [SpringBoot console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOtuO.png)

I want to be able to do development without having to restart.

Comment: Hotswap works fine for me in your project in the IDE build 2023.2.1 when I use CreditApplicationSystemApplication run/debug configuration for running. What changes are you making in the project? Try to focus other application and return to the IDE window after applying changes

Comment: I manage to get springboot reload with another project of mine, but with "credit-application-system" I can't. I redid the test to confirm and the settings were the same as the prints in the post.

Comment: Please contact JetBrains support team directly at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new for a further resolution